# ymax error with stat_bin

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Why am I getting this `ymax` error when doing the following graph in ggplot2? I am trying to create a histogram with some data labels.

```
require(ggplot2)
df=data.frame(ToothGrowth)
ggplot(df,aes(x= len))  + 
  stat_bin(geom="bar", binwidth=5, aes(fill=..count..), colour="black") + 
  stat_bin(binwidth=5, geom="text", aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1.5) +
  facet_grid(.~supp)+
  ylim(c(0,15))+
  theme_bw()
```

Can someone explain to me what the `ymax` parameter is too?

Comment: This is a warning, not an error, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821339/how-to-solve-the-ymax-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by doing:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x= len, ymax=max(..count..)))  + 
  stat_bin(geom="bar", binwidth=5, aes(fill=..count..), colour="black")
```

So by putting the `ymax` parameter in the `aes` and setting it to `..count..` in the situation where you are using `stat_bin`.